# Interpolated result of two sparse data sets (image matching)

Tags: python, image-processing, graphics

I have two sets of [exposure-bracketed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing#Exposure_bracketing) images of a [color chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorChecker) from two different camera systems, A and B. Each data set, at a given exposure, gives me 24 RGB tuples from the patches on the color chart.

I want to match camera B to camera A through a 3-dimensional transform via an interpolation of these two data sets. This is basically the process of creating a look-up table. The methods for parsing and applying LUTs to existing images are well-documented, but I cannot find good resources on how to analytically create a LUT given two different data sets. I know that the answer involves interpolation through a sparse data set, and could involve something like [trilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation), but I'm not sure about the actual execution.

For example, taking the case of trilinear interpolation, it expects 8 corners, but in the case of matching image A to image B, what do those 8 corners consist of? The closest hits to the given pixel in all dimensions? Searching through an unordered data set for close values seems expensive and not correct.

Overall, I'm looking for some advice on how to proceed to match two images with the data set I've acquired, specifically with a 3d transformation. Preferred tool is Python but it can be anything non-proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you need to establish the correspondences, i.e. associate the patches of the same color in the two images (much to say about this but not in the scope of this answer). And get the RGB color values (preferably by averaging over the patches to reduce random fluctuations).

Now you have a set of N pairs of RGB triples, to which you want to fit a mathematical model,

```
RGB' = f(RGB)
```

(`f` is a vector function of a vector argument).

To begin with, you should try an affine model,

```
RGB' = A RGB + RGB0
```

where `A` is a 3x3 matrix and `RGB0` a constant vector. Notice that in the affine case,  the equations are independent, like

```
R' = Ar RGB + R0
G' = Ag RGB + G0
B' = Ab RGB + B0
```

where `Ar`, `Ag`, `Ab` are vectors.

There are twelve unknown coefficients so you need `N≥4`. If `N>4`, you can resort to least-squares fitting, also easy in the linear case.

In case the affine model is insufficient, you can try a polynomial model such as a quadric one (requires `N≥10`).

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, would this technique allow me to generate something more complex than a global 3x3 transformation matrix? A 3x3 matrix is sufficient for linear transformations, but I'm looking for a more complex fit between the two images and want a nonlinear 3D transformation, such as would be provided (typically) by a LUT.

Comment: I answered this, did you read ? Note that "a LUT" means noting as long as you don't know what to fill it with. Also consider that a full RGB LUT has 16777216 entries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I read your answer, just want to make sure I understand. So in this case, a single affine transformation from a 3x3 matrix will be insufficient for the resolution I'm looking for.

Sorry for the ambiguity surrounding "LUT". In this context I'm referring to many film emulation/look LUTs popular in the motion picture industry, typically at a resolution of 32x32x32 or 64x64x64, and containing nonlinear transformations.

Comment: @polyrhythm: how do you know ?

Comment: Because I'm aware of the problem space (in this case, film emulation) and already attempted this with built-in matching tools that produce simple 3x3 matrices that don't offer sophisticated results.

Comment: A page explaining some high level concepts of the sort of transformation I'm after: https://www.lightspace.lightillusion.com/free_look_luts.html

Comment: @polyrhythm: you don't have to tell me about color mapping. The techniques shown in the link are less powerful than an a 3D LUT and, sorry, I am not convinced by your arguments.